# Leaving terms out of the GROUP BY in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I started playing with SQLite I noticed that the GROUP BY lets you leave unaggregated terms out of it. Example:

```
SELECT month, category, max(quantity)
from Table1
GROUP BY month;
```

This will give me an output where I get the `max(quantity)` per month, but then I also get a value for `category`.

What is `category` actually giving me? Does it give me the category that maps to the max(quantity) for the month (which I would normally have to accomplish with a self-join)? Or is just completely arbitrary (and if it's completely arbitrary why would they not just give me an error instead of letting me think that my query worked???)?

I would have ignored the fact that it lets me do that as an oversight except that I found [this tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/) that looks like they're leveraging the fact that you can leave terms out of the group by (unless I'm misunderstanding the tutorial).

EDIT I also just tried it out and found that the two below queries give me the exact same output:

Both queries are looking for the max(update_at) value per cust_id and then also outputting the segment of that cust_id.

**Query 1 (using self-join):**

```
SELECT seg.cust_id, seg.seg_name, temp.max_update
FROM segments as seg
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT cust_id, MAX(update_at) AS max_update
    FROM segments 
    WHERE DATE(update_at) <= "2016-03-01"
    GROUP BY cust_id
) as temp
ON
seg.cust_id  = temp.cust_id AND
seg.update_at = temp.max_update;
```

**Stupid SQLite query (exploiting SQLite's "quirk"):**

```
    SELECT cust_id,seg_name, MAX(update_at) 
    FROM segments 
    WHERE DATE(update_at) <= "2016-03-01"
    GROUP BY cust_id;
```

So is this just a coincidence that they return the exact same results? Or am I missing something? I ran the second version repeatedly to see if it would give me different results and it gave me the same results each time.

Comment: Surprising that query in SQLite even compiles. I thought only MySQL allowed it as it is not valid ANSI SQL. Every other RBDMS I know  correctly fails with such a statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite allows bare columns in aggregate queries for compatibility with MySQL. You [get the values from some random row in the group](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset), so this is useful only when you know that these values actually are the same in a group.

However, there is an [extension](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg) that applies in your case:

> When the min() or max() aggregate functions are used in an aggregate query, all bare columns in the result set take values from the input row which also contains the minimum or maximum.

So your query is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you!! I feel so validated now lol. I leveraged this in a technical interview where they made me use SQLite and they thought it was incorrect (as did I when I first discovered it). But I validated the results several times against self-joins and kept getting the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

From ["SELECT", "3. Generation of the set of result rows"](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset):

> - (...)
>     Each expression in the result-set is then evaluated once for each group of rows. If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, it is evaluated against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group. If there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set, then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row.
>     (...)

So yes, you get just the values from a randomly chosen row within the group.

And why it is like that? Well, likely because the designers/programmers of SQLite decided to do it that way. Probably because it's easier and/or they didn't think this was so important. Like the MySQL people, BTW. It's the same there, at least in lower versions or with some settings.

Comment: That's what I thought. But then why am I getting the same results if I write the query properly vs writing it incorrectly (see EDIT in original post)? I'm annoyed because I noticed I was getting the results I wanted to I started using the "SQLite" version of GROUP BY as a shortcut in an exercise that I handed in which turns out is completely incorrect now :/

Comment: @andraiamatrix: As you already guessed it's coincidence. Well, sorry for you, but that can happen. Tests (as well as problem descriptions) solely or mostly based on a few examples always bear the risk to miss something.

Comment: So CL found the answer in the sqlite documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg Turns out for max and min it actually does give the corresponding value, which is how I had used it. Probably not a good habit to get into though.